# How set value in JsonNode (Convert to ObjectNode)?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Sorry, this is a dumb question, but I really can't figure out why I'm getting an error

My imports:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
```

I have:

```
Class MyObject {
  private String fieldId;
  private JsonNode value;
}
```

And:

```
List<MyObject>;
```

Json with List of MyObject-s:

```
"array": [
                {
                    "fieldId": "id",
                    "value": 10
                },
                {
                    "fieldId": "name",
                    "value": "Random name"
                },
                {
                    "fieldId": "can anything",
                    "value": false
                }...
```

i need to rewrite some values:

```
for(MyObject myObject: array){
          if(myObject.getFieldId.equals("name"))
          ((ObjectNode) myObject.getValue).put("value", "new name");
}
```

but, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode cannot be cast to class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode and com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Please tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: It seems that your `value` is already a ValueNode that contains `10`, `"Random namd"` and `false`.

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand how to be in this case...

No single argument put method for
`((ObjectNode) myObject.getValue).put("new name")`

Answer (score 0):

```
for (MyObject myObject: array) {
    if (myObject.getFieldId.equals("name")) {
        myObject.value = TextNode.valueOf("new name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! 
But I don't understand how, because JsonNode is immutable, but  'myObject.value = ' - value change action.

Comment: The deserialization process has already extracted `Random name` from `{"value": "Random name"}` and stored `Random name` in `MyObject.value`.  You might wrongly think that `MyObject.value` is storing `{"value": "Random name"}`.

Comment: MyObject.value does not store {"value": "Random name"}?

Comment: To verify, you can examine the output of `myObject.value.toString()`.

Comment: code:
`if (myObject.getFieldId.equals("Random name")) {
  log.info("value before: {}", myObject.getValue().toString());
  myObject.setValue(TextNode.valueOf("new name"));
  log.info("value after: {}", myObject.getValue().toString());
}`
output:
`Random name`
`new_name`